# How to attach graalvm-ce-19.2.0 source code in IDE?

Tags: java, graalvm

I installed graalvm-ce-19.2.0 (`/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-19.2.0/bin/java`) and GraalVM contains `/usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-19.2.0/src.zip` file. All java core files are open fine but not classes from `org.graalvm.polyglot.*`. How to attach sources to Eclipse IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources for the `org.graalvm.polyglot` package can be found under `jre/lib/boot/graal-sdk.src.zip`. Those can be attached to `graal-sdk.jar` in the IDE. In general GraalVM contains `*.src.zip` files with the sources next to the corresponding `.jar` files.